# Can we have tabs within a data grid table to group rows?

Tags: data-tables

I am designing a data table which has huge number of rows. Thus I am planning to design a nested grid via grouping of rows.
My objective is to set groups within the table, so that the users can navigate to the relevant rows quickly. 
I have created 2 options as of now:

1. I am thinking to create accordion after expanding a row,
2. Create tabs to filter.

However I am not able to refer to any data grid live examples with tabs inside or any other interaction mechanism. Can anyone help me with some reference or some other idea?

[image: Option 2]

[image: Option 1]

Comment: I think the tabs are a great idea (better than accordion at least)

Comment: I think its too much of data to digest, it might add more confusing. IMHO

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention whether you've looked at the working examples from third-party providers. For example:

- work your way down the left menu [on this Telerik page](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx).
- work your way down the left menu [on this DevExpress page](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Default.aspx).

These sites tend to cater more to developers, not UX practitioners, so you may find it a bit of a challenge.

That's why you might want to sit down *with* a developer from your team and have a good look at what's possible, together.

Hope this helps you move forward.

Comment: I had looked a couple of UI libraries....like smartGWT, bootstrap etc however thanks for your opinion and the links....